# Why is this Mailer giving an error after applying validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error is coming in the create method user mailer section.
I am trying to resolve it, but nothing happens.
How can it be resolved? I come when I apply the validations.

The error is: `Expected a URI like gid://app/Person/1234: #<URI::GID gid://email>`

My mailer controller:

```
  class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
      def welcome_email(user)
      @user = user

      @url  = 'http:3000//example.com/login@u'

      mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')

     end
 end
```

My user controller:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def new
        @user = User.new
       end

   def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
         @user.save
          UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later[here the error come about the invalid url]  
        render 'token'
    end     

     def verify 
        @user = User.authenticate(params[:auth_token])
         if @user
         redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
         else
         flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
         render 'token', :alert =>"Invalid email or password"
       end
   end


   def edit 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end 

   def update
        @user =   User.find(params[:id])
          if @user.update(user_params)
          redirect_to new_login_path
          else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

   private
      def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :dob, :email, 

     :password, :confirm_password, :auth_token)

      end
   end
```

Comment: Show us the mail template as well. :)

Comment: On which line of the mailer the error appears?

Comment: in create method where we call the mailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass the Mailer an unpersisted object, ie. an object that was not saved to the database.

From your code, that means that the previous `@user.save` statement failed probably due to a validation error. In that case, you don't want to send the email anyway.

Change your `create` action like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
    render 'token'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'User was not saved'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: and how can i send a non persisted AR object in a mailer? (i am making a email test feature to send an email preview by creating a fake object to fill the email and send it to my admin email)

Comment: @pastullo Well, then I guess you should ask a new question, provide all the details for your context. You can cite me and I'll have a look.

Comment: thanks man, i eventually solved the problem by creating the AR object in the mailer method, so it works even if it's not persisted